# Mate screenshot area works in terminal, but not in hotkey

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, mate

When I type `mate-screenshot -a` into my terminal, I'm given crosshairs and everything is dandy. However, my declared keyboard shortcut with command `mate-screenshot -a` just takes a screenshot of the whole desktop. What's going on here?

Comment: Old topic with no answer. I have the same problem. What is funny: "--interctive" option works well.

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug in mate-screenshot: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues/37

Answer (score 2):

This can also be done as a one-liner in the keyboard shortcuts, in case anyone else still has this problem:

```
bash -c "sleep 0.1; mate-screenshot -a"
```

is working well for me

Comment: even `sleep 0.01` works

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be a race condition with the interaction between the MATE shortcut system and mate-screenshot. You can work-around the bug by creating a wrapper `/usr/local/bin/mate-screenshot-wrapper` similar to this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
exec /usr/bin/mate-screenshot $@
```

Then assign your custom shortcut to `/usr/local/bin/mate-screenshot-wrapper -a`. On my system I can get away with reducing the `sleep 1` to `sleep 0.1`.

Hat tip: https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-utils/issues/37#issuecomment-155736099